# How are automounted attached volumes provisioned?

Tags: digital-ocean

I created and attached a volume to a Droplet:

```
resource "digitalocean_volume" "main" {
  name = "backups"
  initial_filesystem_label = "backups"
  region = var.region
  size = 50
  initial_filesystem_type = "ext4"
  description             = "A volume for backups"
}

resource "digitalocean_volume_attachment" "main" {
  droplet_id = digitalocean_droplet.main.id
  volume_id  = digitalocean_volume.main.id
}
```

I noticed the volume is automounted under `/mnt/`, and this file appearing on the droplet: `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-backups.mount`. I'm curious as to how the file `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-backups.mount` got provisioned and whether it can be disabled.